# How to rename a column in a query in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is this query right for changing the name of a column in the employees table:

```
select first_name, rename_column('first_name' to 'empName') from employees;
```

Comment: Do you want to change the column name in this one query, or do you want to change it permanently in the database schema?  One is a DML statement that you can do easily, and the other is a DDL operation that requires sufficient privileges to execute it (and won't be a SELECT statement).

Comment: yes i only want to change column name in this query not permanently.
and i want to change hire_date to TENURE On December 31 2014;

Answer (score 6):

there are two ways
1) give alias name to the column

```
 SELECT first_name AS emp_name 
 FROM employee;
```

2) change column name

```
   alter table employee
rename first_name  to emp_name ;
```

Comment: Just RENAME doesn't work for me in Oracle, with RENAME COLUMN everything went fine

Answer (score 2):

To set an alias for a field use the following:

```
SELECT first_name AS "empName", hire_date AS "Tenure On December 31 2014"
FROM employees;
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes for identifiers.

Comment: if i want to rename hire_date to TENURE On December 31 2014;

Comment: @Waseem Mubasher, see updated answer.  Is that what you are after?  Or did you want `hire_date AS "Tenure On December 31 2014"`?

Comment: yes i want  hire_date AS "Tenure On December 31 2014"

Answer (score 0):

```
   alter table employee
rename column first_name  to emp_name ;
```

Comment: It would help to explain this will permanently change the column name potentially breaking other queries!

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_column_name TO new_column_name;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to change the name just in your current result-set, you can do following:

```
select first_name AS emp_name from employees;
```

if you are going to change the name permanently, you have to work with ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE employees CHANGE first_name emp_name VARCHAR2(255);
```

Comment: `CHANGE first_name emp_name ...` is invalid for Oracle. See the manual for the correct syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2183480