# Python Simple Salesforce Select AS Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, simple-salesforce

I'm trying the standard SELECT ... AS call to rename a column in query output with the Python Salesforce API and it's throwing following error:

```
 ... unexpected token: 'AS'", 'errorCode': 'MALFORMED_QUERY'}
```

So far most native language calls from SOQL have been working in the API and it seems, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732615/how-to-rename-a-column-in-a-query-in-oracle), that SELECT ... AS is valid SOQL.

Query outline:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username=myusername, password=mypassword, security_token=mytoken)
query = "select closedate as Date from opportunity"
query_list = sf.query_all(query)['records']
```

**edit**
error remains even after putting the new column name within quotes as advised in above link:

```
query = "select closedate as \"Date\" from Opportunity"
```

Thanks

Comment: Oracle SQL is not the same as SOQL; the question you've linked cannot help you, unfortunately. In fact, based on [this feature request](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEA2QAM) it's currently impossible to alias a column in SOQL unless you're aliasing the result of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Terminus mentioned, SOQL field aliasing is not possible in SOQL in most contexts, including yours. The only case in which I have seen aliasing working in SOQL is in aggregate queries. For example, in apex you could write:

```
AggregateResult myResult = [SELECT count(Id) SpecialName FROM Contact];
system.debug(myResult);
```

and receive the result:

```
DEBUG|AggregateResult:{SpecialName=1630}
```

In python via simple-salesforce it would look like this:

```
sf.query_all('SELECT count(Id) SpecialName FROM Contact')
```

with the result:

```
   OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1),
             ('done', True),
             ('records',
              [OrderedDict([('attributes',
                             OrderedDict([('type', 'AggregateResult')])),
                            ('SpecialName', 6587)])])])
```

Please mark as answered if this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be incorrect.

Try `query = "select closedate <insert alias> from Opportunity"` according to the alias notation documented here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm

Comment: Does it not describe alias notation in a select statement?